# Python: "IndexError: invalid index into a 0-size array"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Obviously, there are loads of threads concerning index errors. But I couldn't find one that helped me out.

I use numpy.loadtxt to read in a function f(a,b).

```
a, b, f = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=' ', usecols=(0,1,2), unpack=True)
```

To get a 2d plot I found a solution in another thread, where you raster the (a,b)-plane and associate an integer tuple (ida, idb) with each point.

```
ncols, nrows = np.round((a.max() - a.min()) / da).astype(np.int) , np.round((b.max() - b.min()) / db).astype(np.int)
ida = np.round((a - a.min()) / da - 1).astype(np.int)
idb = np.round((b - b.min()) / db - 1).astype(np.int)
```

Then put f into the a grid.

```
grid = np.empty((nrows, ncols), dtype=np.float)
grid[idb, ida] = f
```

This worked out well for several data files. But now, suddenly it doesn't. Instead it reports the error in the title when reaching the grid[ida,idb]-line. So I looked for a mistake in the data file, but I couldn't find any. I tried

```
print ida.shape
print idb.shape
print f.shape
```

which returns

```
(3107,)
(3107,)
(3107,)
```

so all arrays match well in size and especially none of them is an empty array. What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Alice

Comment: The interesting object is grid...

Comment: can you post complete error traceback?

Comment: Thanks to seberg's advice, I found the mistake: In loadtxt I imported the wrong columns from the file. One happened to be constant. So I got nrows=0. And _grid_ was the 0-size-array.

Comment: I can't close the thread thoguh without an answer it seems. And I can't write an answer myself until 8h have passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to seberg's advice, I found the mistake (and I also found old stackoverflow account):

```
a, b, f = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=' ', usecols=(0,1,2), unpack=True)
```

I imported the wrong columns from the file. One happened to be constant. So I got nrows=0. And grid was the 0-size-array.

Sorry...